# C++ Array Index

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing

I'm trying to make a black jack like card program in c++, but one of the restrictions is that the array of the cards has to contain both the suit and value of the card, i.e 2H, 3H, 2C, 3C, and so on. How would I do this?

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: I'm just having trouble figuring out how to make the index of the array have both of those components at the same time.

Comment: That's easy. Just put all the suits and the values of the card into a separate array of their own, and your index will simply be an index into that array.

Comment: something like `char cards[][2] = { {2,'H'}, {3,'H'} };`

Answer (score 1):

## Create an [`enum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) for `Suits`

```
enum Suits { Spades, Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts };
```

## Create a [`class`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class) for `Card`

```
class Card
{
  private:
    Suits suit;
    int value;

  public:
    Card(Suits s, int v);
};

Card::Card(Suits s, int v)
{
    suit = s;
    value = v;
}
```

## Create your array (or [`vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)) in `main`

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int size = 6, total_colors = 4, total_values = 13;
    std::vector<Card> v;

    // Fill the vector with random cards
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        v.push_back(Card((Suits)(i % total_colors), i % total_values));

    return 0;
}
```

## Notes

- This will allow you to manipulate your cards **using only one index**. Which is cleaner and more maintainable than creating separate arrays for each *attribute* the `Card` might have.
- The `Card((Suits)(i % total_colors), i % total_values)` will create a `Card` based on the *index* `i`, you might want to change the logic so it suits your use case.

Answer (score 0):

So this is similar to how you represent a matrix, except each row would represent a suit.

If I have Ace -> King in each row, the length of the row would be 13. Then you could assign each suit to a particular row. For instance, Hearts could be 0, Diamonds 1, Spades 2, and Clubs 3.

To index any of these values, it would simply be cards[suit * 13 + card], assuming that you name your array cards. So as an example, if I want the 2 of Diamonds, it would be indexed as cards[1 * 13 + 1], as the 2 would be the second card of row diamond is on (assuming the Ace is index 0).

You could even do an enum for the suits, so that the calculation could look like cards[DIAMONDS * 13 + 1]. Additionally, you could use another enum for the cards, to further simplify the indexing to cards[DIAMONDS * 13 + TWO].